# Does Github Actions have templates

Tags: github-actions

As I have repetitve steps in my Github Actions, I would like to create a template. Let's make a example

```
name: ci
on: ["push"]

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: do stuff
        run: |
          bash stuff
```

Is it possible to save only the steps in a separated file? And import afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mentioned in "[Reuse portion of GitHub action across jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70169094/6309)" that reusing GitHub Worfflow is now (Oct. 2021) available.

The documentation "[Reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows)" includes a section "[Reusable workflows and workflow templates](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#reusable-workflows-and-workflow-templates)", which leads to "[Creating workflow templates](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/creating-workflow-templates)"

> If you need to refer to a repository's default branch, you can use the `$default-branch` placeholder.
>
> When a workflow is created using your template, the placeholder will be automatically replaced with the name of the repository's default branch.
>
> For example, this file named octo-organization-ci.yml demonstrates a basic workflow.

```yaml
name: Octo Organization CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ $default-branch ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ $default-branch ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run a one-line script
        run: echo Hello from Octo Organization
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it does not look like github-actions supports reusing workflows. [Not even YAML anchors are supported](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Support-for-YAML-anchors/td-p/30336).

It looks like the only way to share steps (not setup) is to [create actions](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/about-actions).

#### Update: A storm brewing

I have also [caught wind](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/438) of the possibility of reusing actions. Follow the [issue](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/438#issuecomment-643819753) to stay up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, create an action is too much effort for me.

Comment: @RamonMedeiros it's unfortunate indeed, but I will update this answer when anything changes