# Reuse portion of github action across jobs

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

I have a workflow for CI in a monorepo, for this workflow two projects end up being built. The jobs run fine, however, I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the duplication in this workflow.yml file with the setting up of the runner for the job. I have them split so they run in parallel as they do not rely on one another and to be faster to complete. It's a big time difference in 5 minutes vs. 10+ when waiting for the CI to finish.

```
jobs:
  job1:
    name: PT.W Build
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Setup SSH-Agent
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.2.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: |
            ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Setup JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Setup Permobil-Client
        run: |
          echo no | npm i -g nativescript
          tns usage-reporting disable
          tns error-reporting disable
          npm run setup.all

      - name: Build PT.W Android
        run: |
          cd apps/wear/pushtracker
          tns build android --env.uglify

  job2:
    name: SD.W Build
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Setup SSH-Agent
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.2.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: |
            ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Setup JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Setup Permobil-Client
        run: |
          echo no | npm i -g nativescript
          tns usage-reporting disable
          tns error-reporting disable
          npm run setup.all

      - name: Build SD.W Android
        run: |
          cd apps/wear/smartdrive
          tns build android --env.uglify
```

You can see here the jobs have almost an identical process, it's just the building of the different apps themselves. I'm wondering if there is a way to take the duplicate blocks in the jobs and create a way to only write that once and reuse it in both jobs.

Comment: I haven't nailed the correct syntax to achieve it. However, I'm trying to create a local action that runs the duplicated steps inside my main workflow. 
Reference: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Path-to-action-in-the-same-repository-as-workflow/td-p/38761
This seems to be the way to go about it, but currently the job fails and haven't figured out the correct syntax to set this up with the paths.

Comment: Current error: 

```
##[error]Can't find 'action.yml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/Users/runner/runners/2.163.1/work/-client/-client/.github/actions/build-setup-action.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github actions share workspace/artifacts between jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498605/github-actions-share-workspace-artifacts-between-jobs)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As I know currently there is no way to reuse steps
but in this case, you can use `strategy` for parallel build and different variation:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: macos-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        build-dir: ['apps/wear/pushtracker', 'apps/wear/smartdrive']
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Setup SSH-Agent
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.2.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: |
            ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Setup JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8

      - name: Setup Permobil-Client
        run: |
          echo no | npm i -g nativescript
          tns usage-reporting disable
          tns error-reporting disable
          npm run setup.all

      - name: Build Android
        run: |
          cd ${{ matrix.build-dir }}
          tns build android --env.uglify
```

For more information please visit https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategy

Comment: amazing. i was trying to solve a similar but different problem, and your answer saved me

Answer (score 117):

There are 3 main approaches for code reusing in GitHub Actions:

- [Reusable Workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows)
- [Dispatched workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow)
- [Composite Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) <-- it's the best one in your case

The following details are from [my article](https://cardinalby.github.io/blog/post/github-actions/dry-reusing-code-in-github-actions/) describing their pros and cons:

### Reusing workflows

The obvious option is using the ["Reusable workflows" feature](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) that allows you to extract some steps into a separate "reusable" workflow and call this workflow as a job in other workflows.

#### Takeaways:

- Nested reusable workflow calls are allowed (up to 4 levels) while loops are not permitted.
- Env variables are not inherited. Secrets can be inherited by using special `secrets: inherit` job param.
- It's not convenient if you need to extract and reuse several steps inside one job.
- Since it runs as a separate job, you have to use [build artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) to share files between a reusable workflow and your main workflow.
- You can call a reusable workflow in synchronous or asynchronous manner (managing it by jobs ordering using `needs` keys).
- A reusable workflow can define outputs that extract outputs/outcomes from executed steps. They can be easily used to pass data to the "main" workflow.

### Dispatched workflows

Another possibility that GitHub gives us is [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow) event that can trigger a workflow run. Simply put, you can trigger a workflow manually or through GitHub API and provide its inputs.

There are [actions](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=dispatch+workflow+) available on the Marketplace which allow you to trigger a "dispatched" workflow as a step of "main" workflow.

[Some](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch-and-wait) of them also allow doing it in a synchronous manner (wait until dispatched workflow is finished). It is worth to say that this feature is implemented by polling statuses of repo workflows which is [not](https://github.com/aurelien-baudet/workflow-dispatch/blob/master/src/workflow-handler.ts#L122) very reliable, especially in a concurrent environment. Also, it is bounded by GitHub API usage limits and therefore has a delay in finding out a status of dispatched workflow.

#### Takeaways

- You can have multiple nested calls, triggering a workflow from another triggered workflow. If done careless, can lead to an infinite loop.
- You need a special token with "workflows" permission; your usual `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't allow you to dispatch a workflow.
- You can trigger multiple dispatched workflows inside one job.
- There is no easy way to get some data back from dispatched workflows to the main one.
- Works better in "fire and forget" scenario. Waiting for a finish of dispatched workflow has some limitations.
- You can observe dispatched workflows runs and cancel them manually.

### Composite Actions

In this approach we extract steps to a distinct [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action), that can be located in the same or separate repository.

From your "main" workflow it looks like a usual action (a single step), but internally it consists of multiple steps each of which can call own actions.

#### Takeaways:

- Supports nesting: each step of a composite action can use another composite action.
- Bad visualisation of internal steps run: in the "main" workflow it's displayed as a usual step run. In raw logs you can find details of internal steps execution, but it doesn't look very friendly.
- Shares environment variables with a parent job, but doesn't share secrets, which should be passed explicitly via inputs.
- Supports inputs and outputs. Outputs are prepared from outputs/outcomes of internal steps and can be easily used  to pass data from composite action to the "main" workflow.
- A composite action runs inside the job of the "main" workflow. Since they share a common file system, there is no need to use build artifacts to transfer files from the composite action to the "main" workflow.
- You can't use `continue-on-error` option inside a composite action.

Answer (score 13):

Since Oct. 2021, "[**Reusable workflows are generally available**](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-24-github-actions-reusable-workflows-are-generally-available/)"

> Reusable workflows are now generally available.
> Reusable workflows help you reduce duplication by enabling you to reuse an entire workflow as if it were an action. A number of improvements have been made since the beta was released in October:
>
> - You can utilize outputs to pass data from reusable workflows to other jobs in the caller workflow
> - You can pass environment secrets to reusable workflows
> - The audit log includes information about which reusable workflows are used

See "[Reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows)" for more.

[image: workflow]

> A workflow that uses another workflow is referred to as a **"caller" workflow**.
> The reusable workflow is a **"called" workflow**.
>
> **One caller workflow can use multiple called workflows**.
> Each called workflow is referenced in a single line.
>
> The result is that the caller workflow file may contain just a few lines of YAML, but may perform a large number of tasks when it's run. When you reuse a workflow, the entire called workflow is used, just as if it was part of the caller workflow.

Example:

> In the reusable workflow, use the `inputs` and `secrets` keywords to define inputs or secrets that will be passed from a caller workflow.

```yaml
# .github/actions/my-action.yml
# Note the special trigger 'on: workflow_call:'

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      username:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      envPAT:
        required: true
```

> Reference the input or secret in the reusable workflow.

```yaml
jobs:
  reusable_workflow_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    steps:
      - uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
        with:
          username: ${{ inputs.username }}
          token: ${{ secrets.envPAT }}
```

With `./.github/actions/my-action` the name of the `my-action.yml` file in your own repository.

A reusable workflow does not have to be in the same repository, and can be in another public one.

**[Davide Benvegnù aka CoderDave](https://github.com/n3wt0n)** illustrates that in "[Avoid Duplication! GitHub Actions Reusable Workflows](https://dev.to/n3wt0n/avoid-duplication-github-actions-reusable-workflows-3ae8)" where:

- [`n3wt0n/ActionsTest/.github/workflows/reusableWorkflowsUser.yml`](https://github.com/n3wt0n/ActionsTest/blob/fe32f39d831d08c84fec078f6aa912f6fd606568/.github/workflows/reusableWorkflowsUser.yml) references
- [`n3wt0n/ReusableWorkflow/.github/workflows/buildAndPublishDockerImage.yml@main`](https://github.com/n3wt0n/ReusableWorkflow/blob/f89362e4c298f42a89be625eee44c5e85bd8166b/.github/workflows/buildAndPublishDockerImage.yml#L3-L4)

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding code snippets that demonstrate how to use the feature. Currently it is a borderline link-only answer IMO.

Comment: @jtbandes Thank you for this feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the update. To address the spirit of the question, I think it's still unclear how to use the snippets, since `my-action` is referenced in the second snippet but not the first — is my-action supposed to be a file name of the first snippet?

Comment: @jtbandes I have further clarified the answer and added a concrete example.

Comment: `not the special trigger on: workflow_call` I think you mean note ?

Comment: I'm quite sure this answer confuses the reusable workflow with the calling workflow. The job named `reusable_workflow_job` should just define steps of the reusable job.

Now the job which calls that should make use of `- uses: ./.github/actions/my-action` in one of its steps.

Comment: @wiktus239 Do you mean the [official GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#overview) made that confusion? Or did I misinterpret it? (which is quite possible!)

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of reusable action.

```
name:  Test Execution with coverage

on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  test:
    name: Unit test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get
      - name: Run flutter tests
        run: |
          flutter test --coverage --coverage-path \
          ./coverage/lcov.info &&  genhtml \
          ./coverage/lcov.info -o ./coverage \
```

As you notice, this actions gets triggered `on: workflow_call` which means it will be invoked by another workflow and can't be executed on its own.
As a practice such workflows /actions should be defined in a file starting with _ for e.g.

```
_test_with_coverage.yml
```

Now this can be reused in any workflow like below

```
jobs:
  analyze:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/_static_code_analysis.yml

  test:
    needs: [ 'analyze' ]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/_test_with_coverage.yml
```

Above workflow is reusing or calling two separate reusable workflows stored locally in the `.github/workflows` directory