# Reuse Jobs in GitHub Actions Workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I’m migrating a pipeline from Circle CI to Github Actions and am finding it a bit weird that I can only run jobs once instead of creating a job, then calling it from the workflow section, making it possible to call a job multiple times without duplicating the commands/scripts in that job.

My pipeline pushes out code to three environments, then runs a lighthouse scan for each of them. In circle ci I have 1 job to push the code to my envs and 1 job to run lighthouse. Then from my workflow section, I just call the jobs 3 times, passing the env as a parameter. Am I missing something or is there no way to do this in github actions? Do I just have to write out my commands 3 times in each job?

Answer (score 9):

There are 3 main approaches for code reusing in GitHub Actions:

### Reusing workflows

The obvious option is using the ["Reusable workflows" feature](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) that allows you to extract some steps into a separate "reusable" workflow and call this workflow as a job in other workflows.

#### Takeaways:

- Reusable workflows can't call other reusable workflows.
- The `strategy` property is not supported in any job that calls a reusable workflow.
- Env variables and secrets are not inherited.
- It's not convenient if you need to extract and reuse several steps inside one job.
- Since it runs as a separate job, you have to use [build artifacts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) to share files between a reusable workflow and your main workflow.
- You can call a reusable workflow in synchronous or asynchronous manner (managing it by jobs ordering using `needs` keys).
- A reusable workflow can define outputs that extract outputs/outcomes from executed steps. They can be easily used to pass data to the "main" workflow.

### Dispatched workflows

Another possibility that GitHub gives us is [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow) event that can trigger a workflow run. Simply put, you can trigger a workflow manually or through GitHub API and provide its inputs.

There are [actions](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=dispatch+workflow+) available on the Marketplace which allow you to trigger a "dispatched" workflow as a step of "main" workflow.

[Some](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/workflow-dispatch-and-wait) of them also allow doing it in a synchronous manner (wait until dispatched workflow is finished). It is worth to say that this feature is implemented by polling statuses of repo workflows which is [not](https://github.com/aurelien-baudet/workflow-dispatch/blob/master/src/workflow-handler.ts#L122) very reliable, especially in a concurrent environment. Also, it is bounded by GitHub API usage limits and therefore has a delay in finding out a status of dispatched workflow.

#### Takeaways

- You can have multiple nested calls, triggering a workflow from another triggered workflow. If done careless, can lead to an infinite loop.
- You need a special token with "workflows" permission; your usual `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't allow you to dispatch a workflow.
- You can trigger multiple dispatched workflows inside one job.
- There is no easy way to get some data back from dispatched workflows to the main one.
- Works better in "fire and forget" scenario. Waiting for a finish of dispatched workflow has some limitations.
- You can observe dispatched workflows runs and cancel them manually.

### Composite Actions

In this approach we extract steps to a distinct [composite action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action), that can be located in the same or separate repository.

From your "main" workflow it looks like a usual action (a single step), but internally it consists of multiple steps each of which can call own actions.

#### Takeaways:

- Supports nesting: each step of a composite action can use another composite action.
- Bad visualisation of internal steps run: in the "main" workflow it's displayed as a usual step run. In raw logs you can find details of internal steps execution, but it doesn't look very friendly.
- Shares environment variables with a parent job, but doesn't share secrets, which should be passed explicitly via inputs.
- Supports inputs and outputs. Outputs are prepared from outputs/outcomes of internal steps and can be easily used  to pass data from composite action to the "main" workflow.
- A composite action runs inside the job of the "main" workflow. Since they share a common file system, there is no need to use build artifacts to transfer files from the composite action to the "main" workflow.
- You can't use `continue-on-error` option inside a composite action.

Source: my ["DRY: reusing code in GitHub Actions"](https://cardinalby.github.io/blog/post/github-actions/dry-reusing-code-in-github-actions/) article

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31347117)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently in the exact same boat and just found an answer. You're looking for a [Composite Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action), as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242830/in-a-github-actions-workflow-is-there-a-way-to-have-multiple-jobs-reuse-the-sam/65243912#65243912).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Reusable workflows can't call other reusable workflows.

Actually, they can, since Aug. 2022:

> ### [GitHub Actions: Improvements to reusable workflows](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-22-github-actions-improvements-to-reusable-workflows-2/)
>
> Reusable workflows can now be called from a matrix and other reusable workflows.
>
> You can now nest up to 4 levels of reusable workflows giving you greater flexibility and better code reuse.
>
> Calling a reusable workflow from a matrix allows you to create richer parameterized builds and deployments.
>
> Learn more about [nesting reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-a-matrix-strategy-with-a-reusable-workflow).
>
> Learn more about [using reusable workflows with the matrix strategy](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-reusable-workflows).