# Hosting React project on multiple Azure's Static Web Apps instances

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I have a React project that is deployed as Azure's Static Web App by using [this](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-deploy) workflow. It works, but I would like to host my storybook project into another Azure's Static Web App instance.

This is my Github workflow:

```
# This workflow will build and push a web application to an Azure Static Web App when you change your code.
#
# This workflow assumes you have already created the target Azure Static Web App.
# For instructions see https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/get-started-portal?tabs=vanilla-javascript
#
# To configure this workflow:
#
# 1. Set up a secret in your repository named AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN with the value of your Static Web Apps deployment token.
#    For instructions on obtaining the deployment token see: https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/deployment-token-management
#
# 3. Change the values for the APP_LOCATION, API_LOCATION and APP_ARTIFACT_LOCATION, AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN environment variables (below).
#    For instructions on setting up the appropriate configuration values go to https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/static-web-apps/front-end-frameworks
name: Deploy web app to Azure Static Web Apps

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "v2" ]
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches: [ "v2" ]

# Environment variables available to all jobs and steps in this workflow
env:
  APP_LOCATION: "/" # location of your client code
  API_LOCATION: "api" # location of your api source code - optional
  APP_ARTIFACT_LOCATION: "dist" # location of client code build output
  AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }} # secret containing deployment token for your static web app

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    permissions:
      contents: read # for actions/checkout to fetch code
      pull-requests: write # for Azure/static-web-apps-deploy to comment on PRs
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ env.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }} # secret containing api token for app
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match you app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: ${{ env.APP_LOCATION }}
          api_location: ${{ env.API_LOCATION }}
          app_artifact_location: ${{ env.APP_ARTIFACT_LOCATION }}
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ env.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }} # secret containing api token for app
          action: "close"
```

How can I extend this workflow to run another npm command `npm run build-storybook`, point to its distribution folder `storybook-static` on deploy to another Azure's Static Web App instance?

Another solution could be to copy paste this Github workflow into a new file. The issue is that Github doesn't allow me to add another `AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN` into the same Github project.

Comment: You need to create token with different name and edit the yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can host the react app into multiple Azure static Web Apps.

***Check the below steps which worked for me.***

- I have created an Azure Static Web App.
- For the first time my `yml` has created with `secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_<GENERATED_HOSTNAME` token.
- The token is suffixed with the name of the `Static Web App`.

```cs
   azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_<GENERATED_HOSTNAME> }}
   action: "close"
```

> Another solution could be to copy paste this Github workflow into a new file.

- You dont need to create the `yml` file manually.
- While creating the Static App for the second or the n no. of time, same will be repeated (`yml`workflow with app name suffix will be generated)

***Workflows:***

[image]

- You can even check the tokens in the `Settings` => `Secrets and Variables` => `Actions` section in GitHub.

[image]

- Each workflow file will have its own `Build and Deploy` Actions.
- You can make the necessary changes in the required workflow file (run npm command ) based on your requirement.
- This does no effect the existing other Static Web Apps.
- I have tried with 3 Static web apps with the same GitHub repro.

***Output:***

[image]

Once you set up Azure static web app tokens as a Github Secrets, you can create multple jobs in a single Workflow referencing each job for individual app.

But this will make your workflow complex.

Refer [DRY: reusing code in GitHub Actions](https://cardinalby.github.io/blog/post/github-actions/dry-reusing-code-in-github-actions/) and [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242830/in-a-github-actions-workflow-is-there-a-way-to-have-multiple-jobs-reuse-the-sam) if you want to work with the existing Workflows.