# Propagating or setting up GitHub Classroom Workflow

Tags: github

I'm experimenting with setting up GitHub Classroom (after getting really tired of manually running tests for student submissions this term). I picked one of the tests from the class I am just finishing, but for the test script I have there, I need Python 3.10; earlier versions won't do.

I tried setting up `.github/workflows/classroom.yml` to specify the Python version. If I set it to this, in a student repository, I can get my tests to run:

```yaml
    name: GitHub Classroom Workflow

    on: [push]

    jobs:
      build:
        name: Autograding
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
            with:
                python-version: "3.10"
          - uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - uses: education/autograding@v1
```

but (of course) I don't want my students to do this manually whenever they check out an assignment. So, I tried adding the same to the template repository, but that doesn't seem to affect the student repository when I make a new one of those. There, I get the default I got before

```yaml
    name: GitHub Classroom Workflow

    on: [push]

    jobs:
      build:
        name: Autograding
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v2
          - uses: education/autograding@v1
```

Is there a way to specify what the workflow should be for an assignment or classroom? Or a way to get it from the template?

Comment: We're you ever able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I quit my job ;)

Comment: Kidding aside, I did manage a solution, but it was a bit hairy. I merge multiple repos to make a template for the classroom. There is an example here: https://github.com/birc-gsa/gsa-classroom-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or a way to get it from the template?

Your template could include a workflow, meaning [reuse an existing workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows) ([possible since Oct. 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70169094/6309))

The "[Reusable workflows and workflow templates](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#reusable-workflows-and-workflow-templates)" section includes:

> Inside workflow templates, you can also reference reusable workflows to make it easy for people to benefit from reusing centrally managed workflow code.

If your reusable workflow comes with the right `python-version`, nothing will have to be set up manually.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, this does not answer the question. I've also tried editing the template workflow and it just gets overwritten by Github Classroom on clone.

Comment: @seth That is possible (or it might have changed since 2021). Let me know if you find something more accurate.