# How to share/extend/reuse/reference GitHub Workflow?

Tags: github, workflow, github-actions, cd

I have two workflows. One deploys on push to master to a test environment. The other deploys on release to prod environment. They are 90% identical, code copy&paste.

Is there a concept such as extracting part of the duplicate logic and putting it into its own file/partial/fragment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Github Actions have templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230841/does-github-actions-have-templates)

Comment: Unfortunately not. The best one can do now is to create an action, which offers little to no benefit tbh

Answer (score 4):

Reusing workflows in GitHub Actions is available in public beta now:

- [Reusing Workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows)
- [The GitHub Blog](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-10-05-github-actions-dry-your-github-actions-configuration-by-reusing-workflows/)

To summarize, the workflow that has to be reused needs `workflow_call` trigger. The caller workflows can then refer it directly within a job by using `uses` keyword as shown in the following example which is quoted directly from the [GitHub page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow).

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-1:
    uses: octo-org/this-repo/.github/workflows/workflow-1.yml@172239021f7ba04fe7327647b213799853a9eb89
  call-workflow-2:
    uses: octo-org/another-repo/.github/workflows/workflow-2.yml@v1
```

It does have some [limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#limitations) though.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, reusing one workflow YAML in another, is not possible.

This is (was) discussed in several places:

- [How to reuse a whole workflow?](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-reuse-a-whole-workflow/m-p/46477#M6549)
- [Is it possible to reuse workflow yaml to setup similar workflows?](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Is-it-possible-to-reuse-workflow-yaml-to-setup-similar-workflows/td-p/40634)
- [Support for YAML anchors](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Support-for-YAML-anchors/td-p/30336)

As for your particular problem, not all hope is lost.

I have been using [Kojo](https://github.com/dannyben/kojo) - a command line utility that generates files from templates - for exactly this purpose. I have one template file and I generate two workflows - one for stage, one for production. Perhaps it will be of use to you until a more formal solution from GitHub is available.

(Disclaimer: I am Kojo's author).