# How can I eliminate checking in same yml and related scripts into multiple repositories in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have about 50 repositories for micro services that essentially use the same yml and related scripts for GitHub Actions. How can I eliminate duplicate check-ins and manage it from one place?

Comment: I believe you can't. Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688358/how-to-share-extend-reuse-reference-github-workflow/61714491#61714491